# sin and cos animations on a curved line with javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, trigonometry

I am trying to use sin and cos to animate a CSS image to move on [this shape](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/11/8dd18472440f35412bccc9ad3f045fd5-full.png). Can not make the CSS image to move on that curved bezier line.

Can someone assist on how to use sin or cos in so, if a CSS object added, it would move smoothly along [such a line](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/11/8dd18472440f35412bccc9ad3f045fd5-full.png)?

Here is the code that I tried to make the yellow circle to move on that line with sin and cos math in javascript.

Thanks

```js
var field = document.getElementById("field");
 var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
 var ball2 = document.getElementById("ball2");

 var maxX = field.clientWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
 var maxY = field.clientHeight - ball.offsetHeight;

 var duration = 5; // seconds
 var gridSize = 50; // pixels

 var start = null;

 function step(timestamp) {
  var progress, x, y, y2;
  if (start === null)
   start = timestamp;

  progress = (timestamp - start) / duration / 1000; // percent

  x = progress * maxX / gridSize; // x = ƒ(t)
  y = 2 * Math.sin(x); // y = ƒ(x)
  y2 = 2 * Math.cos(x);

  ball.style.left = ball2.style.left = Math.min(maxX, gridSize * x)
    + "px";
  ball.style.bottom = maxY / 2 + (gridSize * y) + "px";
  ball2.style.bottom = maxY / 2 + (gridSize * y2) + "px";

  if (progress >= 1)
   start = null; // reset to start position
      requestAnimationFrame(step);
 }
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#field {
 position: absolute;
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
 z-index: 50;
 top: 20px;
 left: 20px;
}

#ball {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 50%;
 width: 40px;
 background: yellow;
  z-index: 5;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 200px;
}

#ball2 {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 50%;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
  /*background: silver;*/
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
 <div id="ball"></div>
 <div id="ball2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the code you've tried, perhaps it's an easy fix to your code, and you'll learn more from having your code corrected rather than written for you

Comment: Code snipped added

Comment: your code does nothing at all

Comment: Well, it did a while ago. I am working on a fix.

Comment: The visibility was set to hidden, now it is removed.

Comment: I see the issue though ... you need to call `requestAnimationFrame(step);` inside step as well if you want animation - when you read the *[documentation™](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)* you'll see a note ... *Your callback routine must itself call requestAnimationFrame() if you want to animate another frame at the next repaint.*

Comment: Well it does actually, only the shape of the sin is wrong for the moment, the movement should rather be similar to the link rather than the movement, that is currently set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` calls the given function exactly ONCE

to animate, you need to call `requestAnimationFrame` within that given function, usually calling the function itself (though more complex animations may call something else, it doesn't matter)

The main point being, you need to call `requestAnimationFrame` for each frame you want to animate

```js
var field = document.getElementById("field");
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
var ball2 = document.getElementById("ball2");

var maxX = field.clientWidth - ball.offsetWidth;
var maxY = field.clientHeight - ball.offsetHeight;

var duration = 5; // seconds
var gridSize = 40; // pixels

var start = null;

function step(timestamp) {
  var progress, x, y, y2;
  if (start === null)
    start = timestamp;

  progress = (timestamp - start) / duration / 1000; // percent

  x = progress * maxX / gridSize; // x = ƒ(t)
  y = -2 * Math.cos(x); // y = ƒ(x)
  y2 = 2 * Math.cos(x);

  ball.style.left = ball2.style.left = Math.min(maxX, gridSize * x) +
    "px";
  ball.style.bottom = maxY / 2 + (gridSize * y) + "px";
  ball2.style.bottom = maxY / 2 + (gridSize * y2) + "px";

  if (progress >= 1)
    start = null; // reset to start position
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```css
#field {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 50;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 200px;
}

#ball2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: silver;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="field">
  <div id="ball"></div>
  <div id="ball2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything looks good, even the movement, only the up and down movement, sine wave movement, has to move on [this thick line](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/11/8dd18472440f35412bccc9ad3f045fd5-full.png) rather than having the sine-wave movement it currently has. I rather needed to know on how to change the sin and cos to have it move along the thick line in the link.

Comment: so, the grey ball needs to be inverted from its current movement? changing grid size to 40, and inverting the result for ball2 seems to do the trick

Comment: More like the only visible ball has to be yellow ball, and the yellow ball has to move along the line on this [link](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/9/11/8dd18472440f35412bccc9ad3f045fd5-full.png), the yellow ball has to be the only ball visible while the ball moves on that thick line as seen in the link.

Comment: well, the yellow ball needs an inverted cosine path not a sine path - but at least you have an animation now

Comment: There are not very many examples on the cosine path and its integration, can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, it moves along a path, but I would like to alter that path´s shape so it would look like the thick line on that link I have referenced a lot.

Comment: the -cosine path ...?

Comment: Yes, the cosine path if you say so it is, the path has to be like the thick line, right now, the ball is moving on a sin path line, hence the up and down movement. But the ball has to move on the line on the link, so yes the cosine path has to look like the thick line in that image.

Comment: Basically, I would like the gridSize to be 30, but have a cosine movement, that your animation has. Starting from the left edge and moving to the right edge.

Comment: Also, this information is crucial: #field {
 position: absolute;
 height: 200px;
 width: 360px;
 top: 80px;
 left: 0px;
}